# Throws scribejava NoClassDefFoundError when sending a post request in rest assured with Consumer Key and Secret

Tags: java, rest-assured

Here is my postman post request's screenshot.
[image]

I have below dependencies in my pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scribe/scribe -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
            <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my rest  assured java code .

```
@Test
        public void token() {
            String myconsumerKey="demokey";
            String myconsumerSecret="demoObject";
             JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject()
                    .put("ProfileName","demoProdile")
                    .put("Count",1);

            String uri="https://demo.com/";
            Response res = (Response) given()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .auth().oauth("consumerKey",myconsumerKey,
                            "consumerSecret",myconsumerSecret)
                    .body(jsonObj.toString()).when().post(uri);
    }
```

However , it throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/scribejava/core/builder/api/DefaultApi10a

I checked few answers here but couldn't find any viable solution . Thanks in advance . Full error log is given below .

```
 FAILED: tokensam
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/scribejava/core/model/Token
    at io.restassured.internal.http.AuthConfig.oauth(AuthConfig.java:183)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.AuthConfig$oauth.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.authentication.OAuthScheme.authenticate(OAuthScheme.groovy:35)
    at io.restassured.authentication.AuthenticationScheme$authenticate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:816)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:816)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1661)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:816)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:175)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at com.mavenselenium.RestAssuredFrameWork.HelloOathOne.tokensam(HelloOathOne.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.scribejava.core.model.Token
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 100 more
```

Comment: if you want to use ScribeJava, the simple OAuth client Java lib!, then use this [dependency](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava#pull-it-from-maven-central).

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work still throws  the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/scribejava/core/model/AbstractRequest . I only want to use rest assured and I only added scribe because it's asked to be entered .

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to use the 3.0.6 version of rest assured when the latest version is 4.3.0 ?

Comment: No ,  I changed to the 4.3.0 but it still the same .

Comment: Please  help on this . Thank you .